# How to solve such problems ${]}{-}\infty,2{[}\cup{]}{-}3,5{[}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to solve such problems ${]}{-}\infty,2{[}\cup{]}{-}3,5{[}$ ?

Should I just write the result directly or derive it (how?) ? Also is it sufficient to show that on a number line and then conclude the result?

Also another question , what is this equal to: $[-3,-2]\cap[1,+\infty[$

Thank you so much for your interest.

In general, given a finite set of intervals (open, closed, or half closed) and an expression formed by intersections and unions of them, how to write the result as a finite union of disjoint intervals? Give and step-by-step algorithm.

Comment: « obligatory hate comment against $]a,b[$ notation »

Comment: Draw the intervals on the real line.

Comment: The key to solving these problems is to (a) understand interval notations, (b) visualize intervals, (c) understand what $\cap$ and $\cup$ mean. Once you have these three down, all problems of these sorts are easily do able.

Comment: I don't know, depends on how much detail is expected, and that is very course-dependent. My inclination would be to just write down the answer. The second set is the empty set.

Comment: @anon Many countries use the notation $]a,b[$ for open interval.

Comment: Thanks everybody! Of course I know the interval put on the real number line solution and that's what i will do ! :)

Comment: @user116472: Do you **really** think anyone can understand what you wrote without **any** difficulty? Make our job easier, which is helping you...

Comment: @ABC: I downvoted. Problem?

Comment: There's no doubt that the problem intends you to use whatever method you want to visualize the interval combination (I, and probably everyone else, suggest you draw the intervals) and write down the simplest representation using interval notation (or $\emptyset$). Don't just submit a picture of the number line.

Comment: @user116472: Actually, there is no problem, just an expression. I assume, the problem you are asking for is how to simplify the expression. You might want to add that.

Comment: @Don While I detest $]a,b[$ notation, this question is very understandable. The notation is almost surely not a choice on OP's part anyway. I take serious issue if you're downvoting OP for something that is neither a big deal (purely as a stylistic choice, were it one) nor is even likely to be their fault to begin with.

Comment: @anon: I cannot understand the problem. I think that is in accordance with the down-votes policy.

Comment: The problem is perfectly valid and interesting too. Given a boolean expression of intervals $\cup_{i}\cap_{j}...\cup_{t}I_{i,j,...,t}$. How to write it as $\cup_i J_i$ with $J_i$ disjoint intervals.

Comment: @Don You are taking the policy literally to such an extent that you are downvoting a newbie for no good reason. Do you give any and all readers permission to go through all of your questions and answers and downvote them simply for not understanding them, even if for example the reason we don't understand them is because we do not have the same background as you? (Keeping literalism in mind.) I think you are just being a bully and feigning dumb.

Comment: @anon: That has happened many times (received many down votes for a genuine attempt). Please do not disregard my feelings.

Comment: The question was if you give permission to do that. I suppose I should add, do you think it's fair, and invite others to downvote you simply to be literal with the downvote policy, even if for no other reason. I, for one, do not condone this sort of behavior.

Comment: @anon: An eye for an eye. Because those vote unfairly onto me, I may vote unfairly (in your eyes) if **I cannot understand the question**. I hope this answers your problem.

Comment: @ABC: Please don't add paragraphs to the post. Moreover this question is **absolutely** not the type of questions that should be marked as [logic] and certainly not [set-theory].

Comment: @user116472 the title and first sentence of your question should be improved (what are "such problems?").  The rest makes it clearer.  I have seen worsely-worded problems asked here and answered without anyone complaining, but you should improve yours.

Comment: @Stefan: No, probably not. Doesn't mean it has something to do with [set-theory] and [logic], though.

Comment: No, ofcourse it doesn't have anything to do with set theory, **absolutely** not. Except that the first topic in set theory is algebra of sets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_set_theory_topics).

Comment: @ABC : I replaced the (combinatorics) tag with (elementary-set-theory)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I replaced the (combinatorics) tag with (elementary-set-theory)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The  two intervals overlap - their intersection is the interval $]-3,2[$, or if you prefer $(-3,2)$ - so you can simplify into a single interval

Comment: OP's first question has a union symbol.

Comment: @anon: Yes, and the fact they have an intersection shows that their union is a single interval

Answer (score 0):

There's very little to do.  Just draw the set on the real number line and write it as a (perhaps empty) disjoint union of intervals and/or singletons going from left to right.

As far as a "step by step algorithm" is concerned, you don't need one, unless you are programming a computer to do the problem.

If I asked this problem of a student and s/he justified his/her answer using a picture, that would be fine with me.  If I wanted a formal proof, with quantifiers and such, I would ask for it explicitly.

Comment: No, it is not unreasonable. If the question says, "write it as..." and you answer by "write is as ..." How is this an answer? I am not saying it is difficult, but imagine you have to make a computer do it. Given the expression as input, how do you describe the procedure, the algorithm that "write it as ..."

Comment: @ABC : I'll tweak my answer a bit.  I would consider a picture adequate justification, and wouldn't demand a formal proof.  And I _did_ say that this was my opinion.